# Element <com.google.ads.AdView> is unknown error when I hit ctrl+space

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I want to get content assist working with the admob sdk but it gives me an error

```
Element <com.google.ads.AdView> is unknown.
```

the SDK is setup correctly I think because everything else is working, the ads are showing up on my app.

Anyone know what could be the problem?